# how to create expansion view data from list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i have no idea to create expansion view using data from list

expect :

i have List of user

if data in List just 1 will look like :

[image: 1 user]

if data in List more than 1 will look like :

[image: more than 1]

so, if data more than 1 card can be expansion and hide

any idea to create this ? please, give me suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using `ExpansionTile`.

Example:

```
ExpansionTile(
      expandedAlignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: defaultPadding, right: defaultPadding, bottom: defaultPadding),
      title: widget.question.question.toText(),
      children: [
        widget.question.answer.toText(color: AppTheme.lightGrey),
      ],
)
```

[image: Output]

This was just a simple example. To create custom `ExpansionTile`, you may follow this article by Rob Jones, [Creating a Custom ExpansionTile in Flutter](https://medium.com/swlh/creating-a-custom-expansiontile-in-flutter-53d87a803732)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use ExpansionTile widget to achieve this functionality.